# the [domains] tag versus [domain-names]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags

Is there any difference between [domains](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/domains) and [domain-names](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/domain-names)? If there is, I'm not following the distinction.

Should these tags be merged?

Answer (score 6):

A merge to [domains](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/domains) seems advisable, given that the "names" qualifier is superfluous within the webmaster taxonomy and the shorter form is more likely to be used by those tagging their own questions.

Comment: ok, merging them then, and synonymizing